# Angular2 component vs Angularjs Directive

Tags: angularjs, angular

Is there any similarity or difference in between angular2 component and Angularjs directive. It looks like these 2 are similar and common functionality in angular2 component and Angularjs directive.

At the same time angular2 also have a directive concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

excerpts from [ARCHITECTURE OVERVIEW](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html)

> While a component is technically a directive, components are so
>   distinctive and central to Angular applications that this
>   architectural overview separates components from directives.

You may read about Components [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#components) & Directives [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#directives).
These explain the concepts quite in depth.

Hope this helps!!