# Can I use Directives to render HTML with new Angular 2 RC6 directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

The new Angular RC6 update has changed they way Directive is declared and used. In Angular 1.x I have used directives to output HTML. I want to achieve the same in Angular 2 RC6. The documentation on Angular2 website suggests to use @Input and other methods for data binding. But I can't see a way to render HTML using a Directive. 
I would like Directive to take an Input from parent component and then call a service and render some HTML back. I am able to send input and calling data service but how to send the HTML back?

**update:** Is it because that @Directives doesn't have View and they are solely for the purpose of adding behaviour to existing HTML Elements?

If yes, then what is the best way to make a reusable component?

Comment: You have got Components for that in Angular 2... Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812996/angular2-component-vs-angularjs-diractive/39813223#39813223)

Comment: A useful thing to know about Angular is, "Directives are Components without Templates". So yeah you use a directive to apply to html, but components hold the templates. 

Also note though, you can just grab a ViewChild's "nativeElement", and load up it's innerHTML, and/or you can just bind an elements innerHTML to some property in your component, e.g. <div [innerHTML]="someVariableInMyController"></div>. You can even do this by doing an HTTP get for a page, grabbing the _body of that page in the response, and using that as the inner HTML (which is my workaround for the missing ng-include).

Comment: @MadhuRanjan If all you want is to wrap some logic, adding a component requires adding a new DOM element. If you start doing that for everything, your HTML is going to be a mess and your DOM is going to be really heavy. Not all abstractions are HTML components